# ではないか Grammar translation

Tags: grammar, translation

what does

> ではないか

mean in the sentence below?
And can someone please translate it?

> 耳に馴染みのない方も多いのではないかと思いますが、 (after that he explains the word)....

Answer (score 9):

A は B ではないか is asking "isn't A (=) B?", and here used as a (stylized) *rhetorical question*, i.e. meaning "I think that A is B".

Since A と思いますが is "I think that A, but ...", we are also dealing with an *ellipsis* (assuming you're quoting the whole sentence).

In any case, both figures of speech are very commonly used in Japanese.

Unfortunate for a straight-forward translation is that basically both parts translate to "I think that". In English, we can try to translate it like

> 耳に馴染みのない方も多いの **ではないか**¹ と思いますが **…**²
> I think that a number of people **might**¹ not be familiar with [this] **…**²

Comment: If you consider the quotative particle と as literal quotation marks, you can get a grammatical translation that's pretty literal: I think, "Are not many people not familiar with [this]?" but [...] (Edit: It's worth noting that I don't actually think this is a **good** translation)