# Indirect question marked with かが

Tags: grammar, particle-か, subordinate-clauses

My questions relate to the following two sentences taken from the website referenced below. The goal of the lesson was to explain the uses of ということ but I'm more concerned with the choice of particles in bold.

> 冬に北海道に行ってみればどんなに寒い**か**ということ**が**わかるだろう。
>
> 冬に北海道に行ってみればどんなに寒い**かが**わかるだろう。
>
> If you go to Hokkaido in the winter, (I bet) you'll see how cold it is.

**First, is the second sentence grammatical?**
I thought か replaced が when it marks indirect questions? If it is grammatical, how does including both particles change the meaning?

**Second, is it possible to mark an indirect question with が rather than か?**
For example, is - 冬に北海道に行ってみればどんなに寒い**が**わかるだろう。 - grammatical?

**Last, why is か used in the first sentence at all.**
I was under the impression that と alone is proper and かと actually serves the purpose of reducing the certainty which is not the intention in this sentence.

Reference: http://maggiesensei.com/2010/04/24/request-lesson-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86toiu-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%EF%BC%88toiukoto-and-many-more/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"second sentence" -- 冬に北海道に行ってみればどんなに寒いかがわかるだろう。<-- this is fine.

Second,  冬に北海道に行ってみればどんなに寒いがわかるだろう。 - grammatical? ----> NO

---

( "いるのではないか と" )  (It didn't get solved in March.)[Usage of か I keep encountering](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32726/usage-of-%e3%81%8b-i-keep-encountering)

(There were more answers in Jan.) [Can someone explain how this massive sentence works](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30560/can-someone-explain-how-this-massive-sentence-works)

---

They sound interesting together, but there is nothing special about the かが combination.

I think of this mid-sentence か as another noun-maker.

この方法で良いかを考えた。　　　ＳＴＡＰ現象が起こったかについて論じた。

I can't find any page on it in English.  Is there one?

> http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/57meisisetu.html
>
> ５７．名　詞　節
>
> 57.1　  概観 
>   　　57.2　  「～の」と「～こと」：述語の種類  
>   　　57.3　  Ｖ－ところ
>
> 57.4　  ～か（どうか）
>
> 突然、どうすればいいか(が)わかった。
>    結婚記念日はいつだったか(を)すっかり忘れてしまった。
>    これで良いか(どうか)(を)聞いてみた。
>    この方法でうまくいくか(どうか)(を)試してみよう。
>    このことを知らせるべきか(どうか)(で／に)迷った。
>    その時、彼女がいたかどうか(を／は)忘れました。
>   ？その時、彼女がいたか(を／は)忘れました。
>    これまでのやり方でいいかどうか(を)決めたい。
>    そううまく参りますかどうかはわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

寒いか。
Is it cold?

どんなに寒いか。
How cold is it?

どんなに寒いかが分かる。
I know how cold it is.

分かる
To know

ことが分かる。
To know things.

どんなに寒いかということが分かる。
I know such a thing as how cold it is.

The か is a question particle. 
The が is an object marker for 分かる。