# How to treat embedded questions and が

Tags: grammar, embedded-question

What is the difference between following sentences?

> できるかどうか分かりません
> できるかどうか**が**分かりません

Both seem to have about similar amount of hits on google for an exact phrase.

When reading about embedded sentences they don't tend to mention が to follow them, so it's probably not が would be grammatically required. If that is so, what is its function?

[This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/9719) mentions that を can be used, but no mention of が

[This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25361/9719) asks about と, which seems to make it a quote, but don't know if it necessarily changes the meaning

[This post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39320/indirect-question-marked-with-%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8C) seems close but the answer bottom makes it seem like が is required by the nature of 分かる while other sources teach it without it.

Comment: Note that 分かる is [non-canonical](http://www.lib.kobe-u.ac.jp/repository/81001551.pdf) and licenses either a ガ・ガ or ニ・ガ argument structure, while a canonical argument structure would look more like ガ・ヲ, for example with a verb like 知る.

Comment: Ooh, you're right. Which would point to the case that it's possible to treat embedded question as a noun as pointed out by the first link (https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/9719) ... if that is so, maybe you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The が here emphasises what comes before it. You could imagine it as a response to a question:

> Speaker A: 何かが分かりませんか。
>
> "Is there something that you don't understand?"
>
> Speaker B: できるかどうかが分かりません。
>
> "I don't understand whether I can do it or not."

It emphasises that Speaker B is unsure about *that* specific thing, the important part of the sentence being not that Speaker B is unsure of something/anything, but that Speaker B is *specifically* unsure of whether or not he/she can do it.

Answer (score 1):

In our daily conversation, we tend to omit が and を. For example, we write ケーキ**を**食べますか？ but we say ケーキ食べますか？

It is the same for できるかどうか分かりません and できるかどうか**が**分かりません. The former is casual and the latter is for former writing.

を is used because of 知らない. Please memorize を+知らない and が+分かります. This is standard grammar.

For these sentences 雨がいつ降るかと大変楽しみにしていましたが、なかなか雨が降りません。and 雨が降ることを大変楽しみにしていましたが、なかなか雨が降りません。The former gives me a feeling that the person is looking forward to the rain more. As another user has mentioned- more excited to the rain.