# what does では do in それが人の本質だからでは

Tags: particles, anime

what is the difference between

```
それが人の本質だからでは
```

and

```
それが人の本質だから
```

saw this in an episode of attack on titan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This では is short for [ではないか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17947/5010), which roughly means "..., isn't it?". For example, 夢では means "It's a dream, isn't it?" or just "Isn't it a dream?".

> それが人の本質だから**では**
> = それが人の本質だから**ではないか**
>
> It's because that is the true nature of humans, **isn't it**?

Comment: Can では be also short for ではない?

Comment: @JimmyYang Yes, see [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/74018/5010). But usually いいえ or an ellipsis is present when non-interrogative ではない is intended. Otherwise the sentence would look too confusing.